# Javascript slideshow white screen

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm building a javascript slider for my portfolio with Javascript. The slides work properly but when i add a fading transition i keep getting a white flash between the 2 slides. Anyone knows how to create a smooth fade between them?

Here's my working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t9ezr8wr/2/

My javascript:

```
$(function () {
var theInterval; // Slide speed
var images = new Array();
var counter = 1;
var defaultSettings = {
    "sliderContainer": "#slider" // SliderContainer
    , "pauseWithMouse": true // Turn on/off pause with mouse
    , "sliderSpeed": 3000 // Slide speed
    , "transitionSpeed": 200 // transition speed
};
// intialize slider   
// if myImages exists then
images = myImages;
if (images.length > 0) {
    $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImg" width="900" src="' + images[0] + '" />');
    startSlide(images);
}

function cycleImages(images) {
    if (counter >= images.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    console.log(counter);
    document.getElementById("sliderImg").src = images[counter];
    counter++;
    var images = $('#sliderImg')
    var now = images.filter(':visible')
    var next = now.next().length ? now.next() : images.first()
    var speed = defaultSettings.transitionSpeed; //Transition speed
    now.fadeOut(speed);
    next.fadeIn(speed);
}

function startSlide() {
    console.log('start');
    theInterval = setInterval(function () {
        cycleImages(images);
    }, defaultSettings.sliderSpeed);
    // Set interval time
};
var stopSlide = function () { // Stop slides on hover
    console.log('stop');
    if (defaultSettings.pauseWithMouse) {
        clearInterval(theInterval);
    }
};
$('#sliderImg').on('mouseover', function () { // Stop slides on mouseover
    stopSlide();
});
$('#sliderImg').on('mouseout', function () { // Continue with slides on mouseout
    startSlide();
});
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is ```now.fadeOut()``` and ```next.fadeIn()```. I think that ```now``` fades out completely before ```next``` even begins to fade in - this means that there is a brief period between ```now``` ending and ```next``` starting where there are no images visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what u wanted couldn't be achieved with one image ,so i used two image to achieve the desired effect.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var theInterval; // Slide speed
    var images = new Array();
    var counter = 1;
    var defaultSettings = {
        "sliderContainer": "#slider" // SliderContainer
        , "pauseWithMouse": true // Turn on/off pause with mouse
        , "sliderSpeed": 3000 // Slide speed
        , "transitionSpeed": 600 // transition speed
    };
    // intialize slider   
    // if myImages exists then
    images = myImages;
    if (images.length > 0) {
        $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImg" width="900" style="display:block" src="' + images[0] + '" />');
        $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImg2" width="900" style="display:none" src="' + images[1] + '" />');
        startSlide(images);
    }

    function cycleImages(images) {
        if (counter >= images.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        console.log(counter);
        document.getElementById("sliderImg").src = images[counter];
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("sliderImg2").src = images[counter >= images.length ? 0 : counter];
        var images = $('#sliderImg')
        var now = $("#sliderImg")
        var next = $("#sliderImg2")
        var speed = defaultSettings.transitionSpeed; //Transition speed

        now.fadeOut(speed);
        next.fadeIn(speed,function(){
            document.getElementById("sliderImg").src = document.getElementById("sliderImg2").src;
            $("#sliderImg").css('display','block');
            $("#sliderImg2").css('display','none');
        });

    }

    function startSlide() {
        console.log('start');
        theInterval = setInterval(function () {
            cycleImages(images);
        }, defaultSettings.sliderSpeed);
        // Set interval time
    };
    var stopSlide = function () { // Stop slides on hover
        console.log('stop');
        if (defaultSettings.pauseWithMouse) {
            clearInterval(theInterval);
        }
    };
    $('#sliderImg').on('mouseover', function () { // Stop slides on mouseover
        stopSlide();
    });
    $('#sliderImg').on('mouseout', function () { // Continue with slides on mouseout
        startSlide();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 737px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#slider img {display:none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}

#slider img:first-child {display:block;}
#slider img:nth-child(2) {display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Now i understand why the flash appeared!

Comment: ur  welcome :) 
,yup , with single image there will be a point with no image i.e between transition but in case of two image , both fade in and out at the same time....

Answer (score 0):

The flash effect it's because your next picture is already visible before the call of fadeIn() function, you fix it with add next.hide() just before now.fadeOut().

```js
$(function () {
    var theInterval; // Slide speed
    var images = new Array();
    var counter = 1;
    var defaultSettings = {
        "sliderContainer": "#slider" // SliderContainer
        , "pauseWithMouse": true // Turn on/off pause with mouse
        , "sliderSpeed": 3000 // Slide speed
        , "transitionSpeed": 800 // transition speed
    };
    // intialize slider   
    // if myImages exists then
    images = myImages;
    if (images.length > 0) {
        $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImg" width="900" src="' + images[0] + '" />');
        startSlide(images);
    }

    function cycleImages(images) {
        if (counter >= images.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        console.log(counter);
        document.getElementById("sliderImg").src = images[counter];
        counter++;
        var images = $('#sliderImg')
        var now = images.filter(':visible')
        var next = now.next().length ? now.next() : images.first()
        var speed = defaultSettings.transitionSpeed; //Transition speed
        next.hide();
        now.fadeOut(speed);
        next.fadeIn(speed);
    }

    function startSlide() {
        console.log('start');
        theInterval = setInterval(function () {
            cycleImages(images);
        }, defaultSettings.sliderSpeed);
        // Set interval time
    };
    var stopSlide = function () { // Stop slides on hover
        console.log('stop');
        if (defaultSettings.pauseWithMouse) {
            clearInterval(theInterval);
        }
    };
    $('#sliderImg').on('mouseover', function () { // Stop slides on mouseover
        stopSlide();
    });
    $('#sliderImg').on('mouseout', function () { // Continue with slides on mouseout
        startSlide();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 737px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}
    
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#slider img {display:none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}

#slider img:first-child {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      var myImages = ["https://s4.postimg.org/45u9pqnml/slide1.jpg", "https://s11.postimg.org/f3qwh4syb/slide2.jpg", "https://s24.postimg.org/b365xoq7p/slide3.jpg"];
  </script>
  <main>
  <div id="slider">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hmm okay, but still flashing :(

Comment: @user3205743 With your implementation you can do it better cause you have only one image displayed, to get a continue transition you need to display 2 images at the same time. But it would be better if you do that with a special framework or a JQuery plugin. plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel

Comment: But thanks your solution is actually better than i thought! The fade is already much better now! I'll go on with finding out how to already load the second slide!

Answer (score -2):

try to change transitionspeed to 0

Comment: I need the transitionspeed for the fade between the slides

Comment: In future, try to keep such small comments and suggestions to the question's comment section please.